# Чистка логов Nginx'а

Tags: nginx, логирование

У апача логи автоматически сами собой архивируются. Как сделать то же самое для Nginx, чтобы логи не разрастались?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь logrotate. Создайте файл:

```
/etc/logrotate.d/nginx
```

и добавьте в него:

```
/var/log/nginx/*log {    daily    rotate 9    missingok    notifempty    compress    sharedscripts    postrotate        [ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`    endscript}
```